# how to imRotate with OpenCV 2.4.3?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, rotation

how can i implement imrotate(Mat src,Mat dst,double angle) using **OpenCV 2.4.3**?
there is a function **warpAffine()** but it does to much more and is confusing. and it crops what goes out of bounds.

i want it to make a bigger the canvas to fit everything. and fill empty spots with black.

Comment: i'm using c++ opencv 2.4.3.

Comment: Did you check the opencv tutorials ? It says to find rotationmatrix for the desired angle and then use warp affine. Isn't it sufficient?

Comment: actually it crops my edges after rotation ineed it all. iwant it make  a larger canvas  to fit everything and add black on empty spots.

Comment: You could write your own function 'imrotate' which actually creates a big canvas(may be size of diagonal length of image) and rotate the image on it and use that function.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it like this. thank to your answer.

```
Mat rotateImage(const Mat source, double angle,int border=20)
{
    Mat bordered_source;
    int top,bottom,left,right;
    top=bottom=left=right=border;
    copyMakeBorder( source, bordered_source, top, bottom, left, right, BORDER_CONSTANT,cv::Scalar() );
    Point2f src_center(bordered_source.cols/2.0F, bordered_source.rows/2.0F);
    Mat rot_mat = getRotationMatrix2D(src_center, angle, 1.0);
    Mat dst;
    warpAffine(bordered_source, dst, rot_mat, bordered_source.size());  
    return dst;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use `copyMakeBorder` with scalarAll(0) for the original image, then use the rotation matrix and transform using `warpAffine`. The border should be large enough to contain the rotated image. Use `warpAffine` with `CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS`, again with scalarAll(0)