# Equivalent function of Matlab's imrotate function in OpenCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

While trying to convert the Matlab's `imrotate` function into OpenCV, I got different results.

In Matlab:

```
A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6];
rotA = imrotate(A, 45, 'bilinear', 'crop');
```

This gives me:

```
rotA = 
   0.7233    2.7929    5.2233
   1.3520    4.2071    2.3520
```

In OpenCV, I did:

```
cv::Mat A = cv::Mat::zeros(2, 3, CV_32FC1);
A.at<float>(0, 0) = 1;
A.at<float>(0, 1) = 2;
A.at<float>(0, 2) = 3;
A.at<float>(1, 0) = 4;
A.at<float>(1, 1) = 5;
A.at<float>(1, 2) = 6;
cv::Mat rotationMatA = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(cv::Point(1, 1), 45, 1.0);
cv::Mat rotA;
cv::warpAffine(A, rotA, rotationMatA, rotA.size());
```

And this gives me:

```
rotA = 
      1.1875   3.5625   3.5625
      2.125    5        1.6083984
```

What caused this difference? And how can I obtain the same result as that of Matlab? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am guessing that the rotation center. Try with a 3x3 matrix or with the center at (1,0.5)

Comment: Changing the center indeed affects the result, but how can we decide the center so that it gives exactly the same result as of Matlab? Center at (1, 0.5) gives me: [0.36035, 2, 4.875;   0.59375, 3.4375, 2.96875].

Comment: The center in Matlab is the middle point of the Matrix, thats why I susggested you to try (1,0.5). Have a look inside imresize, you may find something

Comment: Use this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870089/how-to-imrotate-with-opencv-2-4-3