# How to implement the imrotate functioin using OpenCV

Tags: c++, matlab, opencv

Yes. I want to get the same result like the imrotate in matlab, but I can't get the point.
More specifically，I get a mat A

> a =

```
 1     2     3
 4     5     6
```

> > > imrotate(a, 45)

ans =

```
 0     0     0     0     0
 0     0     3     6     0
 0     1     2     6     0
 0     1     4     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0
```

How can I do that using OpenCV?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to imRotate with OpenCV 2.4.3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14870089/how-to-imrotate-with-opencv-2-4-3)

Comment: Different in what way? What have you tried in OpenCV? What were the results? How do they not match what you got in MATLAB?

Answer (score 1):

You may need use getRotationMatrix2D and warpAffine.
like this:

```
Mat     A(5, 5, CV_8U, Scalar(0));  
Point   center(3, 3);  
double  angle = 45;  
int value=1;
for (int i = 2 ; i<4 ;i++)
{
    for (int j = 1 ; j <4 ;j++)
    {
        A.at(j,i) = value;
        value++;
    }
}
Mat matrix = getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0);
Mat imgRotation;  
warpAffine(A, imgRotation, matrix, Size(5, 5));
```